# Did Trump tweet the most liked Persian language tweet in history?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump, iran, twitter

Saeed Ghasseminejad (advisor to a foreign policy think tank) [claimed](https://twitter.com/SGhasseminejad/status/1216131659986325504) yesterday:

> This tweet by 
>   @realDonaldTrump
>    with more than 100k likes is already the most liked Persian tweet in the history of Twitter. A strong show of support by Iranians for Trump's Iran policy, something the MSM does not and will not report.

This claim was immediately re-reported by the [Washington Examiner](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/trump-tweet-in-farsi-the-most-liked-persian-tweet-in-history-of-twitter).

Granted the U.S. President has a wide audience especially in America, but there are *a lot* of Farsi (Persian) speakers.

Did President Donald Trump tweet the most liked Persian language tweet ever?

Comment: One problem with investigating this would be working out if a “like” is genuine, or by a bot or an employee of the Russian government.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The origin of the like isn't part of the question.

Comment: @Gryphon I would say that it is. The claim specifically notes that this is "a strong show of support by Iranians". If there is evidence that most of the likes are from US citizens (or Russian bots, or whatever), then only the first part of the claim would be true. But the second part is much more important here (I doubt that the Washington Examiner would have written about it if it were just about an interesting factoid without the political implications).

Comment: @tim, my primary question is about the first part of Ghasseminejad's statement. The second -- I assume -- is far too subjective (what is "strong"?) and would make for a poor skeptics question.

Comment: @tim, as noted by the OP, the question itself asks solely about whether the first part of the claim is true.  The fact that the original author of the claim goes on to draw conclusions is largely irrelevant to the question at hand, whether the tweet in question is, in fact, the most liked Persian tweet.

Comment: @Gryphon But without viewing the context and implications of the original claim, the question is quite meaningless and answers ignoring the context would be rather misleading. If we were to get a question about a claim such as "It was very cold in January. A strong sign that climate change is not real, something the MSM will not report" and OP only asked if it really was very cold in January, then IMHO that wouldn't make a great question (though it would be on-topic). Any answer which completely ignores the second part of the original claim would IMHO be a very poor answer.

Comment: @tim, again, I assumed "strong show of support" would far too subjective a claim to verify on skeptics (what is "strong"). But yeah that'd be **great** to know as well. Knock yourself out.

Comment: Isn't Twitter blocked in Iran?

Comment: Is the claim that it's the tweet most liked by Persians/Iranians, or is it that, of tweets written in Farsi, it's the most liked?

Comment: @Acccumulation, the latter. Claim is "most liked Persian tweet", not "most Persian-liked tweet".

Comment: Really? What's the Persian for "covfefe"?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Twitter is indeed blocked in Iran. However, usage of VPNs to bypass the block is very common.

Comment: @b0fh But that just is a little nudge toward the "support by Iranians for Trump's Iran policy". Without access to service you cannot use service to show your support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the claim is currently true, but may or may not have been true at the time of the claim.

[I am going to use the timestamps shown to me by Twitter; these may be regional and differ for you.]

[Twitter's advanced search](https://twitter.com/search?q=lang%3Afa%20min_faves%3A90000%20&src=typed_query&f=live) currently shows only five distinct tweets with above 90,000 likes with Farsi as the language:

- March 15th, 167.8K likes for [video of a woman belly-dancing on an electrical pole](https://twitter.com/arashxuxu45/status/1106488236166115328).
- January 12th, 8:46am, 368.8K likes for Trump's [tweet in question](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1216130169477439488).
- January 12th, 9:50am, 268K likes for another Trump's [tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1216130169477439488), also in Farsi.

At January 12th, 9:55am, [Saeed Ghasseminejad made his claim](https://twitter.com/SGhasseminejad/status/1216131659986325504).

After that there were more relevant tweets:

- Mark Hamill [quote tweeted](https://twitter.com/HamillHimself/status/1216154351971880960) Trump's first Farsi tweet. It currently has 279.5K likes.
- Mark Hamill quote tweeted another of Trump's (English) tweets. It currently has 159.3K likes. [Edit: Link was wrong, and I can't find it now.]

If Trump's tweet *only* had 100K likes at the time of the claim, then the belly-dancer would still be more popular, but at the time I wrote this answer, Trump's tweet was most popular.

There are some potential sources of error:

- A deleted tweet (or a Farsi speaker who blocked me on Twitter!) may beat those numbers.
- Twitter may display different numbers of likes to different people.
- The Twitter Search feature is not reliable. Tweaking the search to change the minimum number of likes means it sometimes, incorrectly, doesn't show any of these tweets.
- I can't be sure that there isn't a campaign since the claim to push the belly-dancing tweet up in numbers in an attempt to overtake Trump's tweet.

(The part of Ghasseminejad's claim that this was evidence from a strong show of support by Iranians for Trump's Iran policy is not justified. It is likely a substantial number of the likes were his English-speaking supporters.)

Comment: [A Reddit post of a screen recording of a retweet of the original tweet of the dancing video](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlackPeopleTwitter/comments/b1tcdc/bust_down_khadijah/) The post was made March 16th, 2019 and it shows 123K Twitter likes.

Comment: Your second Mark Hamill re-tweet is actually a Trump tweet in Farsi, not English. Was that intended?

Comment: Also, when you say `Twitter may display different numbers of likes to different people.` is that just a possibility or is there something that suggests that?

Comment: @Mooz: It wasn't intended. Thank you. I haven't been able to find the original. Twitter showing different counts to people is just a theoretical possibility, but given an understanding of caches and "eventual consistency" it seems an inevitable one.

Answer (score 28):

Two hours after Donald Trump's tweet, actor [Mark Hamill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hamill) responded with [another tweet in Farsi](https://twitter.com/HamillHimself/status/1216154351971880960) which translates to

> Please ignore the fact that I created a travel ban for you and threatened to bomb your cultural sites

At the time of posting this, Hamill's tweet had 278K likes - more than Trump's 267K likes. As of January 25, [Trump’s tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1216114167108849665) has 369.4K likes, more than Hamill’s 279.7K likes.

You can search for [most popular tweets in Farsi, until 14 January, 2014](https://twitter.com/search?l=fa&q=since%3A2010-01-01%20until%3A2020-01-14%20min_faves%3A100000&src=typd).

Note that Twitter has been banned in Iran since 2009 ([NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/02/technology/iran-protests-social-media.html)).  And though many Iranians are able to circumvent this ban (whether by using a VPN, or by living abroad), this fact does make any statements such as, "A strong show of support by Iranians for Trump's Iran policy, something the MSM does not and will not report" highly dubious.

Comment: The most popular tweets URL is giving me a "Something went wrong" error from Twitter. Is it working for other people?

Comment: The timeline is 1) Trump tweeted, 2) received 100K likes,  3) Ghasseminejad tweeted his claim, 4) Hamill tweeted, 5) at some point Hamill's likes overtook Trump's. It is unfair on Ghasseminejad to cite a counter-example that happened AFTER his claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking That speaks to whether or not this is actually a notable claim if such things are in flux so much, don't you think? And, for what it's worth, that particular tweet has received a *massive* amount of likes in the last hour, showing some clear signs of manipulation.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I've answered the question that was asked.  If the question were, "at the time Ghasseminejad wrote his tweet, did Trump's tweet have more likes than any other tweet written in Farsi," the answer would be different.  For that matter, this answer in no longer correct, since, as Michael W points out, in the past hour Trump's tweet has gotten another 150K likes.

Comment: @Juhasz, every claim is framed to the time it was made. If I claim, *"The U.S. is the only country to have ever landed a man on the moon",* that claim is correct (barring conspiracy theories). If China lands a man there in 2040, that doesn't make me retroactively wrong.

Comment: I note that my Twitter still shows the same figures as the ones I edited in. If other people are seeing Trump's tweets higher, it is probably to do with Twitter's caching mechanism, rather than an unexpected rush.

Comment: @Juhasz, the notable claim is the thing that matters.

Comment: @PaulDraper A statement is either true or false. It doesn't depend on who said it when. If you had said in 2000 "No black person has ever been elected president of the United States", that claim would now be wrong. If someone were to post a question asking whether it's true, the correct answer would be "no". Now, would it merit a caveat that at the time it was made, it was correct? Perhaps. But the **main** answer should still be "no".

Comment: Would you be "wrong"? Arguably not: you weren't wrong, past tense, because you were right at the time, and you are now wrong, because you aren't currently making the claim. But the claim itself is false.

Comment: @Acccumulation, it absolutely depends when it was said. Otherwise, you couldn't conclusively rate claims as "true" or "false." Many would be an open-ended possibilities until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: @PaulDraper Sure you can. Why do you think you can't?

Comment: At the very least, I think you should not open your answer with a "yes" or "no", but with something more like "it was [true/false] at the time it was posted, but is [false/true] now".

Comment: Why do you apply “suspicion” only to Trump’s likes but not Hamill’s?